# Google Cloud Platform - leverage VPC to faciliate KVM to KVM guest communication

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is is possible to use VPC network/subnet to enable communications between guest VM's that live on separate KVM hosts backed by virtual bridging? Please see the image below. Intended flow: VM1 to VM2 (bidirectional)

Question: Can ethernet frame with a source mac address of a guest VM be sent over the VPC, or will it be dropped? I have setup KVM-1 to link it's pnic1 (physical nic connected to VPC) to the virtual bridge used by the KVM hypervisor, and when trying to ping the pnic1 on KVM-2, no packets ever arrive. This leads me to believe the frame is being dropped as it hits the VPC.
[VM1 to VM2 KVM topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFdb5.png)

Comment: In general, the public cloud providers do not provide L2-transparent networks.  I wouldn't expect *anything* below IP to work at all.

Comment: What are KVM-1 and KVM-2 in this image? Why have you brought up Google Cloud? Something doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @womble thank you, and for obvious reasons I understand why. I am trying to test a virtualized environment which is why I am trying to extend L2 between the KVM hosts.

Comment: @MichaelHampton not sure where the confusion is in my post. KVM-1 and KVM-2 are hypervisors running on 2 separate instances created in GCP for nested virtualization.

Comment: There was nothing in your question about nested virtualization, that's the reason for the confusion.

Comment: @MichaelHampton oh, sorry then for the confusion. I didn't put that initially because it's in the cloud thereby inferring 'nested' as L0 virtualization type would be default, unless rented a baremetal server. L0(google instance)>L1(some hypervisor)>L2(some vm in the L1 HV). Anyhow, did you have any input or direction here?

Comment: You can click the edit link to edit your question so that it's clear to readers what you are trying to convey. These comments are only temporary, and some users don't see them. Further, editing the question will also bring it back to the home page, where more people can see it.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?